# Finding Points of Tangency of a Circle and a Parametric Curve

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I have the following Parametric plot

[image]

Generated from the following:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{(A*Cos[t]^2 + B)*{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, 
   C*{Cos[t] + 1, Sin[t]}}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {A, 1, 10}, {B, 1, 10}, {C, 1, 
  10}]
```

I would like to find the exact values of $C$ and $t$ such that the inner circle, with one point fixed to the origin is tangent to the outer curve. This would mean, if I'm not mistaken, for $t\in\left[0,\pi/2\right]$, solving the following system of equations for $t$ and $C$

```
x1 = (A*Cos[t]^2 + B)*Cos[t]
y1 = (A*Cos[t]^2 + B)*Sin[t]
x2 = C*(Cos[t] + 1)
y2 = C*Sin[t]
x1 == x2
y1 == y2
```

i.e. find the intersection of the curves, but also they should have the same tangent, so we have:

```
D[y1,t]/D[x1,t] == D[y2,t]/D[x2,t]
```

But, for some reason I can't find a solution. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to avoid using `C`, `D`, `I`, or `N` as constants in Mathematica. More generally, use initial lowercase for your constants.

Comment: Did mean for the circle to be [osculating](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OsculatingCircle.html) or merely tangent?

Comment: @Michael E2 I guess just tangent (and I added a note about this in my response).

Comment: yes, just tangent is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to calculate anything by hand in MMA. Use `D` and `Cross` to formulate your expectations.

#### One solution can be found analytically:

```
ClearAll[a, b , p1, p2, c]
p1[t_] := (a Cos[t]^2 + b)*{Cos[t], Sin[t]}
p2[t_] := c*{Cos[t] + 1, Sin[t]}

Solve[{
   Cross[D[p1[t], t]].D[p2[t], t] == 0,
   p1[t] == p2[t],
   0 <= t <= Pi/2, c > 1
   }, {t, c}, Reals] // Normal
```

> ```
> {{t -> 0, c -> (a + b)/2}}
> ```

#### General case with `a` and `b` fixed:

```
a = 5; b = 1;
sol = NSolve[{
   Cross[D[p1[t1], t1]].D[p2[t2], t2] == 0,
   p1[t1] == p2[t2],
   c > 1,
   0 <= t1 <= Pi, 0 <= t2 <= Pi}, {t1, t2, c}, Reals]
```

> ```
> {{t1 -> 0, t2 -> 0, c -> 3.}, {t1 -> 1.10715, t2 -> 2.2143, c -> 2.23607}}
> ```

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Join @@ ({p1[t], p2[t]} /. sol)], {t, 0, 2 Pi},
               PlotRange -> {{0, 8}, {-3, 3}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
               Epilog -> { PointSize@.02, Green, p2[t2] /. sol // Point}, 
               PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Black, Blue}, BaseStyle -> Thick]
```

> [image]

#### Edit: with `FindRoot` it can be instantaneous:

(*trivial soluion is not calculated*)

```
ClearAll[a, b, p1, p2, c]
p1[t_, a_, b_] := (a Cos[t]^2 + b)*{Cos[t], Sin[t]}
p2[t_, c_] := c*{Cos[t] + 1, Sin[t]}

Manipulate[
 sol = FindRoot[{Cross[D[p1[t1, a, b], t1]].D[p2[t2, c], t2] == 0, 
                 p1[t1, a, b] - p2[t2, c] == 0},
                {{t1, Pi/2.}, {t2, Pi/2.}, {c, a}}];
 
 ParametricPlot[ Evaluate[{p1[t, a, b], p2[t, c] /. sol}], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
                PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-10, 10}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
                PlotStyle -> {Orange, Blue}, BaseStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> 600,
                Epilog -> {PointSize@.02, Red, p2[t2, c] /. sol // Point, 
                  Point[{(a + b), 0}], Blue, Circle[{(a + b)/2, 0}, (a + b)/2]}, 
                ]
 , {a, 1, 10}, {b, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why does not the following directly work?ClearAll[a, b, p1, p2, c]
a = 5.; b = 1; 
p1[t_, c_] := (a Cos[t]^2 + b)*{Cos[t], Sin[t]}
p2[t_, c_] := c*{Cos[t] + 1, Sin[t]}
NSolve[{Cross[D[p1[t, c], t]].D[p2[t, c], t] == 0, 
   p1[t, c] == p2[t, c], 0 <= t <= Pi/2}, {t, c}, Reals] // Normal

Answer (score 10):

--- edit ---

I forgot to address an issue which I now see was raised in a comment by @Michael E2. This setup is only going to give a tangent circle. If it osculates it is largely by accident. (Outright snogging, now that might be intentional.)

--- end edit ---

The issue is that these curves need not intersect at the same value of the parameter. So you can proceed as below.

```
aa = 2;
bb = 1;
x1[t_] = (aa*Cos[t]^2 + bb)*Cos[t];
y1[t_] = (aa*Cos[t]^2 + bb)*Sin[t];
x2[t_] = cc*(Cos[t] + 1);
y2[t_] = cc*Sin[t];
eqns = Flatten[{x1[t1] - x2[t2], 
    y1[t1] - y2[t2], {D[x1[t1], t1], D[y1[t1], t1]} - 
     lam*{D[x2[t2], t2], D[y2[t2], t2]}}];
sol = Solve[
  GroebnerBasis[eqns, {t1, t2, cc}, lam] == 0 && 0 <= t1 <= Pi/2 && 
   0 <= t2 <= 2*Pi, {cc, t1, t2}]

(* {{cc -> 3/2, t1 -> 0, t2 -> 0}, {cc -> 3/2, t1 -> 0, 
  t2 -> 2 \[Pi]}, {cc -> Sqrt[2], t1 -> -2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]], 
  t2 -> -4 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]}} *)

{x1[t1], x2[t2], y1[t1], y2[t2]} /. sol // N

(* Out[304]= {{3., 3., 0., 0.}, {3., 3., 0., 
  0.}, {-1.41421356237, -1.41421356237, 1.41421356237, 
  1.41421356237}, {1.41421356237, 1.41421356237, 1.41421356237, 
  1.41421356237}} *)
```

A careful look will indicate that there are two such circles. One intersects at the east-most crossing of the x axis.

```
p1 = ParametricPlot[{x1[t], y1[t]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   ColorFunction -> (Green &)];
p2 = ParametricPlot[{x2[t], y2[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   ColorFunction -> (Blue &)];
p3 = ParametricPlot[{x2[t], y2[t]} /. sol[[3]], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   ColorFunction -> (Red &)];

Show[p1, p2, p3]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 because of `GroebnerBasis`

Comment: I _think_ you may explain the role of **lam**

Comment: @Artes Yep, _I_ understand. I was thinking that Daniel's explanation could enrich his answer. Thanks!

Comment: @belisarius Well, I needed to sacrifice a variable. Okay, I could have cross multiplied I guess. But that lam is still getting fleeced.

Comment: The solution looks good, but I don't really understand the method you used. What was wrong with my original attempt (apart from syntax)?

Comment: It fails to take into account that the two curves are parametrized, and the intersection point(s) of interest need not arise from the same value of the respective parameters. Ergo, you need two separate time parameters.